# Insertar nodo en indice especifico de lista enlazada Python

Tags: lista

Buenas ,tengo una duda con esto que no se me puede ocurrir bien como hacerlo, como el titulo lo dice, tengo un Nodo típico y una lista típica

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, info):
        self.info = info
        self.next = None

class list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__first = None
        self.__last = None
```

y tengo que crear la función que inserta el nodo en la posición especifica de la lista dada (pongo acá lo que llevo) (tampoco quiero cambiar algo del nodo, ni tampoco crearle metodos)

```
def indexar(self, info, indice):
    longit = self.tam()
    n = node(info)
    p = self.__first
    if index == 0:
        self.__first = n
    else:
        if index > 0 and index < longit:
```

ya cree la funcion self.tam() que entrega el tamaño de la lista, y ya tengo en el caso que se quiera ingresar en la posición 0, pero ya para una posición X no inicial no puedo lograrlo (mejor dicho, imaginarlo), cualquier tipo de ayuda o recomendación es eternamente agradecido

Comment: Nos dices que no logras hacerlo. ¿Qué falla? ¿Cómo falla?

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que recorrer la lista y cuando encuentres el lugar que le corresponde debes reasignar el puntero next del nodo anterior para que apunten a tu nuevo nodo y el puntero next del nuevo nodo deben apuntar al nodo que sigue en la lista